# How to compare two rows of dates in R and transform into one row

Tags: r, date, transform

I have a data set which contains multiple rows of date information (intervals) for the same names, which should be compared and eventually transformed into one row. I'd like to achieve the following:

- If the intervals are overlapping, then keep one row with the earliest and the latest date of the four values
- If the intervals are not overlapping, but the time between intervals is less or equal to 60 days, do the same as above: thus, keep one row with the earliest and latest date of the four values
- If the intervals are not overlapping, and the time between intervals is more than 60 days, do nothing (keep both rows)

Data:

```
names <- c("John", "John", "Rick", "Rick", "Katie", "Katie", "Harry", "Harry" )
date1 <- c("1-3-2016", "18-5-2016", "13-1-2018", "4-2-2020", "5-1-2019", "29-1-2020", "27-8-2018", "4-2-2020")
date2 <- c("16-4-2020", "13-2-2020", "2-3-2020", "16-2-2020", "25-2-2020", "10-4-2020", "27-6-2019", "8-4-2020")
df1 <- data.frame(names,date1,date2)
```

Desired result:

```
names <- c("John", "Rick", "Katie", "Harry", "Harry")
date1 <- c("1-3-2016", "13-1-2018", "5-1-2019", "27-8-2018", "4-2-2020")
date2 <- c("16-4-2020", "16-4-2020", "10-4-2020", "27-6-2019", "8-4-2020")
df2 <- data.frame(names,date1,date2)
```

Transform the dates:

```
df1$date1 <- as.Date(df1$date1, "%d-%m-%Y")
df1$date2 <- as.Date(df1$date2, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: your sampel data does not cover the usecase to join intervals when there is a gap between intervals smaller than 60 days... so answers below *might* not consider this... Probably wise  to update your sample data, so that is covers all functionality you desire in your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way (probably not the most concise) using `dplyr`. First we convert the dates to `Date` format, then for each name

1. figure out if the second interval starts more than 60 days after the first. If so, we tag both rows as `keep_both`. We sorted the dates so we know the second row comes later.
2. for rows that aren't marked `keep_both`, get the min and max dates. Note that I'm assuming the intervals are in the right order, i.e. `date2` is later than `date1` in each row here.
3. filter the data to keep just the first row from each name unless we are keeping both.

Output matches your desired output except for a typo on Rick.

```r
names <- c("John", "John", "Rick", "Rick", "Katie", "Katie", "Harry", "Harry")
date1 <- c("1-3-2016", "18-5-2016", "13-1-2018", "4-2-2020", "5-1-2019", "29-1-2020", "27-8-2018", "4-2-2020")
date2 <- c("16-4-2020", "13-2-2020", "2-3-2020", "16-2-2020", "25-2-2020", "10-4-2020", "27-6-2019", "8-4-2020")
df1 <- data.frame(names, date1, date2)

library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(c(date1, date2), lubridate::dmy)) %>%
  arrange(names, date1, date2) %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  mutate(
    keep_both = any((date1 - lag(date2)) > 60, na.rm = TRUE),
    new_date1 = if_else(keep_both, date1, min(date1)),
    new_date2 = if_else(keep_both, date2, max(date2)),
  ) %>%
  filter(keep_both | row_number() == 1) %>%
  select(names, date1 = new_date1, date2 = new_date2)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   names [4]
#>   names date1      date2     
#>   <chr> <date>     <date>    
#> 1 Harry 2018-08-27 2019-06-27
#> 2 Harry 2020-02-04 2020-04-08
#> 3 John  2016-03-01 2020-04-16
#> 4 Katie 2019-01-05 2020-04-10
#> 5 Rick  2018-01-13 2020-03-02
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I used slightly altered sample data, to make sure intervals that are <= 60 days apart from each other, get joined as described in the question..

**sample data**

```
names <- c("John", "John", "Rick", "Rick", "Katie", "Katie", "Harry", "Harry" )
date1 <- c("1-3-2016", "28-4-2020", "13-1-2018", "4-2-2020", "5-1-2019", "29-1-2020", "27-8-2018", "4-2-2020")
date2 <- c("16-4-2020", "28-5-2020", "2-3-2020", "16-2-2020", "25-2-2020", "10-4-2020", "27-6-2019", "8-4-2020")
df1 <- data.frame(names,date1,date2)

  names     date1     date2
1  John  1-3-2016 16-4-2020
2  John 28-4-2020 28-5-2020 # !! <-- altered so interval-gap with line 1 <= 60 days
3  Rick 13-1-2018  2-3-2020
4  Rick  4-2-2020 16-2-2020
5 Katie  5-1-2019 25-2-2020
6 Katie 29-1-2020 10-4-2020
7 Harry 27-8-2018 27-6-2019
8 Harry  4-2-2020  8-4-2020

names <- c("John", "Rick", "Katie", "Harry", "Harry")
date1 <- c("1-3-2016", "13-1-2018", "5-1-2019", "27-8-2018", "4-2-2020")
date2 <- c("28-5-2020", "2-3-2020", "10-4-2020", "27-6-2019", "8-4-2020")
df2 <- data.frame(names,date1,date2)

  names     date1     date2
1  John  1-3-2016 28-5-2020  # !! <-- joined, since gap <= 60 days
2  Rick 13-1-2018  2-3-2020  # !! <-- fixed type in your sample data provided
3 Katie  5-1-2019 10-4-2020
4 Harry 27-8-2018 27-6-2019
5 Harry  4-2-2020  8-4-2020
```

**code**

The code makes use of the `data.table` and the `intervals`-packages. Since`intervals` only work on numeric (integer or real) intervals, the date-columns get converted to numeric before interval-creation/-extension/-merging, and back to date-format after processing.

What the code below does:

1. Loop (`lapply()` over cuncks of split (using `data.table::split()` with the `by-argument`. , by name. `keep.by = FALSE` is used, since we do not need it, and the by-name is also stored in the names of the created list.
2. For each cunck (=name), defines intervals based on the two date-columns, and extend these intervals by half the value of the `gap`-variable (set to 60 in the code below). So each interval gets extended by 30 days before and after.
   It then joins overlapping/touching (extended) intervals, and finally removes the extensions.
3. Use `data.table::rbindlist()`, to merge all the results back together.
4. set colnames, and convert numeric values dates back to data-format

.

```
library( data.table )
library( intervals )
#set maximum gap between intervals
gap = 60
#set data to data.table format
setDT(df1)
#set dates to numeric (required by the intervals-package)
df1[, c("date1", "date2") := lapply( .SD, as.numeric ), .SDcols = c("date1", "date2") ]
#where the magic happens (see text above for explanation )
ans <- data.table::rbindlist(
  lapply( split( df1 , by = "names", keep.by = FALSE ), function(x) {
    as.data.table(
    intervals::close_intervals( intervals::contract( intervals::reduce( intervals::expand( 
            intervals::Intervals( x, type = "Z" ), 
            gap/2 ) ), gap/2 ) 
      )
    )
  }),
  use.names = TRUE, idcol = "name" )
#use names from df1
setnames( ans, names(ans), names(df1) )
#set numeric back to date
ans[, c("date1", "date2") := lapply( .SD, as.Date, origin = "1970-01-01" ), .SDcols = c("date1", "date2") ]
```

**output**

```
   names      date1      date2
1:  John 2016-03-01 2020-05-28
2:  Rick 2018-01-13 2020-03-02
3: Katie 2019-01-05 2020-04-10
4: Harry 2018-08-27 2019-06-27
5: Harry 2020-02-04 2020-04-08
```