# Match rows with the same or close start and end date in data.table r

Tags: r, date, data.table, match

Following `data.table`

```
df <- data.table(id=c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
                 start_date=c("2019-05-08","2019-08-01","2019-07-12","2017-05-24","2016-05-08","2017-08-01","2019-06-12","2017-02-24","2017-08-24"),
                 end_date=c("2019-09-08","2019-12-01","2019-07-30","2017-11-24","2017-07-25","2018-08-01","2019-12-12","2017-08-24","2018-08-24"),
                 variable1=c("a","c","c","d","a",NA,"a","a","b"))
df                 
id start_date   end_date variable1
1:  1 2019-05-08 2019-09-08         a
2:  2 2019-08-01 2019-12-01         c
3:  2 2019-07-12 2019-07-30         c
4:  2 2017-05-24 2017-11-24         d
5:  3 2016-05-08 2017-07-25         a
6:  3 2017-08-01 2018-08-01      <NA>
7:  4 2019-06-12 2019-12-12         a
8:  4 2017-02-24 2017-08-24         a
9:  4 2017-08-24 2018-08-24         b
```

Within the same ID, I want to compare the `start_date` and `end_date`. If the `end_date` of one row is within 30 days of the `start_date` of another row, I want to combine the rows. So that it looks like this:

```
id start_date   end_date variable1
1:  1 2019-05-08 2019-09-08         a
2:  2 2019-07-12 2019-12-01         c
3:  2 2017-05-24 2017-11-24         d
4:  3 2016-05-08 2018-08-01         a
5:  4 2019-06-12 2019-12-12         a
6:  4 2017-02-24 2017-08-24         a
7:  4 2017-08-24 2018-08-24         b
```

If the other variables of the rows are the same, rows should be combined with the earliest `start_date` and latest `end_date` as `id` number 2. If the `variable1` is `NA` it should be replaced with values from the matching row as `id` number 3. If the `variable1` has different values, rows should remain separate as `id` number 4.
The `data.table` contains more variables and objects than displayed here. Preferable a function in `data.table`.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two rows of dates in R and transform into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871548/how-to-compare-two-rows-of-dates-in-r-and-transform-into-one-row)   I answered a data.table + intervals solution in this question.

Comment: I am getting following error message   `error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'close_intervals': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'contract': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'reduce': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'expand': invalid class “Intervals” object: The 'Intervals' classes are based on two-column, numeric matrices.` I converted the dates to `as.numeric`.

Comment: See also [identify consecutively overlapping segments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091907/identify-consecutively-overlapping-segments-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what happens if an id has 3 overlapping rows with `variable1 = c('a', NA, 'b')`, what should the `variable1` be for the NA for this case? `a` or `b`?

If we just choose the first `variable1` when there are multiple matches, here is an option to first fill the NA and then borrow the idea from David Aurenburg's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods/28938694#28938694)

```
setorder(df, id, start_date, end_date)
df[, end_d := end_date + 30L]

df[is.na(variable1), variable1 :=
    df[!is.na(variable1)][.SD, on=.(id, start_date<=start_date, end_d>=start_date), mult="first", x.variable1]]

df[, g:= c(0L, cumsum(shift(start_date, -1L) > cummax(as.integer(end_d)))[-.N]), id][,
    .(start_date=min(start_date), end_date=max(end_date)), .(id, variable1, g)]
```

output:

```
   id variable1 g start_date   end_date
1:  1         a 0 2019-05-08 2019-09-08
2:  2         d 0 2017-05-24 2017-11-24
3:  2         c 1 2019-07-12 2019-12-01
4:  3         a 0 2016-05-08 2018-08-01
5:  4         a 0 2017-02-24 2017-08-24
6:  4         b 0 2017-08-24 2018-08-24
7:  4         a 1 2019-06-12 2019-12-12
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(id=c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
    start_date=as.IDate(c("2019-05-08","2019-08-01","2019-07-12","2017-05-24","2016-05-08","2017-08-01","2019-06-12","2017-02-24","2017-08-24")),
    end_date=as.IDate(c("2019-09-08","2019-12-01","2019-07-30","2017-11-24","2017-07-25","2018-08-01","2019-12-12","2017-08-24","2018-08-24")),
    variable1=c("a","c","c","d","a",NA,"a","a","b"))
```